# In data structure, what is the difference between an ordinary heap and a binary heap?

Tags: data-structures, heap

As I know, a binary heap is a heap data structure that takes the form of a binary tree, so that a binary heap is a special kind of heap. But what is the definition of a heap(an ordinary heap).

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)):

> In computer science, a heap is a specialized tree-based data structure
>   that satisfies the heap property: if `P` is a parent node of `C`, then the
>   key (the value) of node `P` is greater than the key of node `C`.

[Binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) is a specific data structure that is based on a complete binary tree.

Heap data structure is a general term. There are many different [heap data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Variants). And the heap is not limited to be a single tree at all (not only binary). Look at the [Binomial heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) for example.